# Return single duplicate row and corresponding value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to return a single duplicate and its corresponding value in the same record in another table. Group by clause and having clause is not working when the ID or any different value is different. I have 2 tables, Table DataTemp and Table Data.

I have to check if Table DataTemp contain a duplicate in the same table and return the document number of its corresponding document in the same select, so that i can insert it in another table.

There is an inner join to find its date that it has been uploaded.

When I remove the ID column and do it, it finds the duplicates but when I add the ID column, it does not return any duplicates even if the column Check_1 is duplicate.

I started from this query which find the duplicates

```
SELECT
TD.Check_1,
COUNT(TD.ID)
FROM
TblDataTemp TD
GROUP BY TD.Check_1
HAVING COUNT(TD.ID) > 1;
GO
```

and it is returning the duplicates, only when i put to get the ID, it returns no results.

```
Check_1                         (No column name)
05/08/2019 00:00:00123120.12         2
```

This is the code that needs to do the job.

```
INSERT INTO TblDuplicatesWorkflow (ID,PostingDate,DocumentDate,Account,Reference,CompanyCode,TaxCode,PaymentCode,Amount,DocumentCurrency,                               DocumentNumber,BarCode,BankType,CorrespondingDocumentNumber, DateUploaded)

SELECT 
        dt.ID,dt.PostingDate,dt.DocumentDate,DT.Account,DT.Reference,dt.CompanyCode,dt.TaxCode,
        dt.PaymentCode,dt.Amount,dt.DocumentCurrency,dt.DocumentNumber,dt.BarCode,dt.BankType,'**Corresponding Duplicate**',td.DateUploaded
FROM
TblDataTemp dt
INNER JOIN TblData td
ON dt.ID = td.ID
GROUP BY dt.ID,dt.PostingDate,dt.DocumentDate,DT.Account,DT.Reference,dt.CompanyCode,dt.TaxCode,
        dt.PaymentCode,dt.Amount,dt.DocumentCurrency,dt.DocumentNumber,dt.BarCode,dt.BankType,td.DateUploaded
HAVING (COUNT(dt.Check_1) > 1);
go
```

so far the select is not returning any result.

Data Temp is as follows:

[image: DataTemp Table]

Comment: Can you show sample data you are having duplicate rows with? Table schema would help as well.

Comment: Sample Added. Check 1 is the duplicate check to be done. I need to have its corresponding document number

Comment: The `ID` column looks like an `Identity` and is probably the PK for this table. In that case there will never be duplicate values. The `Document Number` looks unique as well, so I would start by removing those columns to get the duplicate values in a `CTE`, then find the document numbers based on a combination of values from the `CTE`.